# How run my code in spyder as i used to run it in linux terminal

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, spyder

Apologies if my question is stupid. 
I am a newbie is all aspects.

I used to run my python code straight from the terminal in Linux Ubuntu, 
e.g. I just open the terminal go to my folder and run my command in my Linux terminal

`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python trainval_net.py --dataset pascal_voc --net resnet101 --epochs 7  --bs 1 --nw 4 --lr 1e-3 --lr_decay_step 5 --cuda`

now im trying to use Spyder.

So for the same project i have a folder with bunch of functions/folders/stuff inside it.

So i just open that main folder as a new project, then i have noo idea how i can run my code...

There is a console in the right side of spyder which looks like Ipython and i can do stuff in there, but i cannot run the code that i run in terminal there.

In iphython or jupyther i used to usee `!` at the begining of the command but here when i do it (e.g. `!CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python trainval_net.py --dataset pascal_voc --net resnet101 --epochs 7  --bs 1 --nw 4 --lr 1e-3 --lr_decay_step 5 --cuda`) it does not even know the modules and throw errors (e.g. ImportError: No module named numpy`)

Can anyone tell me how should i run my code here in Spyder

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You'll need to install the same libraries to Spyder as you have in your other copy of Python

Comment: i think spyder already should have them since all the libraries are installed with conda and pip, i dont thinks it is a library issue

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.
I need to go to `run->configure per file` and in the `command line options` put the configuration (`--dataset pascal_voc --net resnet101 --epochs 7  --bs 1 --nw 4 --lr 1e-3 --lr_decay_step 5 --cuda`)